# select from one table more than 10,000 times

Tags: php, mysql

I have table `arseh` that all field is primary key. All fields have index. It has 10,000,000 record.

```
         Arseh Table
------------------------------
|Code|ID|FromYear|ToYear|
-----------------------------
|1   |1 |1350    |1395  |
|2   |1 |1355    |1366  |
|2   |10|1395    |1395  |
```

PHP

```
function Calc($Code,$ID,$FromYear,$ToYear){
    $Handler = new DB();
    $Result=$Handler->query("select * from arseh where Code='".$Code."' and ID=".$ID." and FromYear='".$FromYear."' and ToYear='".$ToYear."'");
    return $Result;
}
```

I need call function Calc more than 10,000 times with different and random parameters.

**Problem:** this scenario(call Calc for 10,000 times) need 20 second to complete. how can decrease this time?

If i insert whole data of table to array one time and other time search in array instead select from table is better ?or not?

Comment: How is your table indexed?

Comment: And does DB create a new database connection every time it's called? or does it use an existing database connection if one has already been set?

Comment: all field have index

Comment: Individual indexes won't be particularly helpful, create a composite index

Comment: `$Handler` use an existing database connection if one has already been set

Comment: @MarkBaker If i insert whole data of table to array one time and other time search in array instead select from table is better ?or not?

Comment: Unlikely to be better loading 10,000,000 records into memory, that takes a lot of time and memory; and your PHP search will be a lot less efficient that searchig on a properly indexed database

Comment: So where is this one at? What is the output from `show create table arseh `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can predict needed data and load much smaller data in query time. 
but the other way is to indexed search that i describe here:

First load all your data and save them in global variable.

Then make two arrays one for `FromYear` while it's index set to FromYear value and the other one for `ToYear` while it's index set to ToYear and both value set to data index .

Then filter ToYear and FromYear arrays by their index and your needs.

Then intersect result values.

Then use the result indexes and return data by select them and return;

I will describe more by an example next...

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical N+1 query problem (google it). You have some cycle that calls Calc() in each iteration, thus creating enormous amounts of SELECTs.

The proper technique is to group your parameters (you mentioned 10000 combinations) and load them in one query. This way you end up with a relatively small dataset and matching becomes much cheaper.

Comment: I do not know about parameters for function Calc() ,these parameter are random

Comment: If you mean you receive the parameters from a database or some other source, you still know all the parameters before running the 10000 iterations. So, instead of iterating and calling Calc() you should load the data first.